# Código se carga, pero no se lee Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

he estado realizando un proyecto cargando un JSON con una lista de datos.
Ahora lo que quiero es ponerles un EventListener a un botón, pero al hacer pruebas no imprime console.log.

El código se lee y existe en la página, pero nunca se ejecuta, sin embargo, al colocarlo en consola directamente indica que la lógica está bien.

```js
//Se añade el JSON

const elementoCarousel = document.querySelector('.menu__cafes');

export function loadjson() {
  fetch('/src/scripts/cafes.json')
  .then(Response => Response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(cafe => {
      html += 
      `
      <div class="menu__cafe">

        <div class="menu__foto">
          <img class="menu__img" src="${cafe.img}" alt="${cafe.nombre}">
        </div>

        <div class="menu__desc">
          <p class="menu__p">${cafe.nombre}</p>
          <p class="menu__p">${cafe.precio}</p>
        </div>

        <button class="menu__btn" type="button">+</button>

      </div>
      `;
    })
    elementoCarousel.innerHTML = html;
  })
.catch(() => {
  alert('No funciona');
})
}


//ESTA PARTE HACIA ABAJO NO FUNCIONA (pero si se lee)

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__btn');

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Funciona');
  })
})
```

Comment: el EventListener, no sería `onClick`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo haces poniendo datos un array directamente funciona, como en este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rzhcpv1/).

Creo que lo que pasa es que como `fetch` es una función asíncrona, entonces cuando añades tus eventos, aun no has terminado de cargar los datos. Prueba cambiar los eventos dentro de un bloque `then` luego de cargar los datos.

```
export function loadjson() {
  fetch('/src/scripts/cafes.json')
  .then(Response => Response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(cafe => {
      html += 
      `
      <div class="menu__cafe">

        <div class="menu__foto">
          <img class="menu__img" src="${cafe.img}" alt="${cafe.nombre}">
        </div>

        <div class="menu__desc">
          <p class="menu__p">${cafe.nombre}</p>
          <p class="menu__p">${cafe.precio}</p>
        </div>

        <button class="menu__btn" type="button">+</button>

      </div>
      `;
    })
    elementoCarousel.innerHTML = html;
  }).then(() => {
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__btn');

    btns.forEach(btn => {
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('Funciona');
      })
    })

})
.catch(() => {
  alert('No funciona');
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás asignando el evento para elementos que todavía no existen en el DOM, una opción es la [respuesta de @CamiloGomez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/451959/54039), moviendo esa parte del código para que se ejecute después de agregar los botones.

La otra es "delegar" el evento, es decir, escuchar los clics en el contenedor y analizar el elemento que disparó el evento:

```
// e es el evento, donde puedes obtener qué elemento lo disparó
elementoCarousel.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Saber si el clic fue en un botón, analizando la clase
    if(e.target.classList.contains('.menu__btn')) {
        // Es un botón, puedes obtener el padre con closest()
        let parent = e.target.closest('.menu__cafe');
        // Desde el padre puedes obtener nombre y precio
        let data = parent.querySelectorAll('.menu__desc .menu__p');
        // Como tienes 2 párrafos, el elemento 0 es el nombre y 1 es el precio
        console.log('Nombre: ' + data[0].textContent);
        console.log('Precio: ' + data[1].textContent);
    }
});
```

Referencias:

- [evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event)
- [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)