# ejecutar evento en js

Tags: javascript

tengo un problem,trato de ejecutar un evento pero al parecer el evento no se crea .
el código es así
da la BD traigo la información de una categoría
entonces con petición ajax creo el elemento asi:

```html
function mostrar_categorias() {
    let $div_mostrar_categorias = document.getElementById('div_mostrar_categorias');
    axios({
            url: 'ajax/traer_categoria.php',
            method: 'get',
            responseType: 'json',

        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('respuesta del servidor')
            console.log(res);
            console.log('********************************')
            let numero_totales_depto = res.data.length;


            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < numero_totales_depto; i++) {
                let $div_categoria = document.createElement('div');
                let tex = document.createTextNode(res.data[i].descripcion);
                $div_categoria.classList.add('col');
                $div_categoria.classList.add('stilo_seccion');
                $div_categoria.setAttribute('data-idcat', res.data[i].id)
                $div_categoria.appendChild(tex);
                //$div_categoria.innerHTML = res.data[i].descripcion;
                $div_mostrar_categorias.appendChild($div_categoria);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

asi respectivamente creo eso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora mi problema a es que creo una función de esta forma :

```html
function guardar_id_categoria(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_categoria', this.dataset.idcategoria);
    localStorage.setItem('id_depto', 0);
    window.location.href = 'publicaciones.php';
}


let $categorias = document.querySelectorAll('[data-idcat]');
console.log($categorias);
$categorias.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', guardar_id_categoria);
});
```

y esta no se ejecuta

les comparto el repositorio de github:
https://github.com/xXMolinaXx/Platam/tree/axios

mi problema esta dentro de la carpeta platam el archivo index.php,el codigo de js esta en la carpeta js y los archivos son index.js y index_ajax

Comment: Cuando haces `console.log($categorias);`, ¿te muestra los resultados que tienes en la captura de pantalla?

Quizá estés tratando de aplicar los `addEventListener()` **antes** de que se impriman los resultados que traes de la base de datos.

Comment: Tu caso es el mismo de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/451957/54039), tratas de asignar eventos a elementos que todavía no existen.

Comment: si ya verifique ese caso que me comentan ,por ende ejecuto primero el codigo para crear esos campos ,despues de crear esos campos creo los eventos pero no me funciona

Comment: ok voy a ver si me ayuda la otra publicacion

Comment: gracias creo que ya me dieron una idea de que es lo que pasa, tratare dé ejecutar ese código dentro de .then de la petición AJAX