# querySelectorAll no me toma ningun item

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un carrito de compras, como es solo una prueba, los productos los genero aleatoriamente a traves de javascript. Mi problema radica en lo siguiente, al seleccionar 'Agregar' los datos de este articulo (precio, codigo, nombre) los coloco en un elemento que se va a crear y creara una lista de los que vaya agregando, cada uno de los elementos de esta lista tienen un elemento `tr`  `class: item` y tambien en el precio tengo un icono de una basura para eliminarlo... Bien, yo quiero tomar todos los elementos que sean mi basura para entonces añadirles el evento para borrar el elemento que este en esa posicion, el problema radica que no me lo esta tomando y no tengo idea de porque, necesito ayuda por favor

```
function agregarArticulos () {

    let item;
    

        agregarBtns.forEach(function(btn, posicion) {
      
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

            alert.classList.add("hidden");

            if (listaArticulos.length > 4) {
            alert.classList.remove("hidden");
            return;
            } 
                
           
            


            item = document.createElement("tr");
            item.className = `item item${posicion}`
            item.innerHTML = `    <td class="name-title name">`+ names[posicion].textContent +`</td>
            <td class="code-title code">`+ codes[posicion].textContent +`</td>
            <td class="price-title title-first price-item">`+ prices[posicion].textContent +` <span class="fas fa-trash btn-trash"></>  </td>`
            table.appendChild(item);
        
            listaArticulos.push(item);  

            
            if(listaArticulos.length > 0) {
                
                carritoBtn.classList.remove("hidden");

            }

         
            
                
        });
    
    }); 

};

// no los toma

let itemList = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

console.log(itemList)

let btnsEliminar = document.querySelectorAll(".price-title .fa-trash");
             console.log(btnsEliminar)
```

Comment: No sé si tenga que ver, pero en tu elemento `span` no lo estás cerrando bien, debe ser: `<span class="fas fa-trash btn-trash"></span>`

Comment: Hola! ya lo cerré sigue sin funcionar muchas gracias por la observacion, es que de igual forma no me toma tampoco los elemento con `.item` si coloco esos `querySelector` dentro de la funcion si me los toma pero alli me causa errores otras cosas, es que no entiendo porque no me va tomando en el NodeList dinamicamenta cada uno de los elementos con la `class: item` cada vez que se les da a agregar

Comment: No toma los elementos porque seguramente no existen todavía y, de hecho, no los necesitas porque puedes [delegar el evento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/451995/54039)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".item")` se ejecuta antes de cualquier click, para que tome un valor "actualizado" debe ir dentro de la función.

Comment: Vale, lo dejará dentro de la funcion, necesito, otra ayuda por favor al hacer esto `function eliminarArticulo(btns) {

    btns.forEach(function(btn) {


        btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

            console.log(e.currentTarget);`  }) }) }; al darle click al `btn` en la pocision '2' por ejemplo en el console.log me salen 3 veces ese evento, si lo hago en la posicion 3 me sale, 4 veces, si lo hago en la posicion 1 me sale, dos veces, esto porque sera? porque se me multiplican?